# Add Section of text if something is added to a JSON file C#

Tags: c#, json

I basically have a program that will check for a JSON file on a website. I wanted to be able to use a List Box to add the objects in when a new one is added, but I only know how to add each object individually.

```
                try
            {

                HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mining.bitcoin.cz/accounts/profile/json/" + APIKey);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String json = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                readStream.Close();
                var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
                uName.Text = ((string)jo["username"]);
                eRewards.Text = ((string)jo["estimated_reward"]);
                uRewards.Text = ((string)jo["unconfirmed_reward"]);
                cRewards.Text = ((string)jo["confirmed_reward"]);
                bRating.Text = ((string)jo["rating"]);
                bHashrate.Text = ((string)jo["hashrate"]);
                walletID.Text = ((string)jo["wallet"]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input API Key", "Mining.BitCoin.Cz", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
```

Comment: Could you give us more information? What is an "event" for you? What do you mean with "add individually"? And what have you done so far?

Comment: @cansik I would Input the other JSON objects in the exact same way as the code above. I was wondering if there is a way to add them in under a whole category, because if a new one was added or taken away, the program will get an error, or if a new one appeared it would not be shown.

Comment: Suggest wrapping your disposables `HttpWebResponse`, `Stream` and `StreamReader ` in [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements.